# How to print a fraction

Tags: c, int, double, precision

I am trying to write a program using struct to find the mid point of two points. However the output is always zero when I try to print the float, and always be the nearest integer (when fraction is needed) when print int. So how could I make this correct that it could print a fraction out. (e.g. when output can be number such as 1.5)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct point{
       int x;
       int y;
};

struct rect{
       struct point pt1;
       struct point pt2;
};

struct point makepoint(int x, int y){
       struct point temp;

       temp.x = x;
       temp.y = y;
       return temp;
}

int main()
{

  struct rect screen;
  struct point middle;
  struct point makepoint(int, int);

  int XMAX, YMAX;
  XMAX = YMAX = 0;

  screen.pt1 = makepoint(0,0);
  printf("Enter the x axis: ");
  scanf("%d",&XMAX);
  printf("Enter the y axis: ");
  scanf("%d",&YMAX);
  screen.pt2 = makepoint(XMAX,YMAX);
  middle = makepoint((screen.pt1.x + screen.pt2.x)/2,(screen.pt1.y +   screen.pt2.y)/2); 

  printf("x = %f, ",middle.x);
  printf("y = %f\n",middle.y);



  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't represent `1.5` using an `int` type variable. Since the `x` and `y` members of `struct point` are of type, you cannot capture `1.5` using an object of type `struct point`.

Answer (score 3):

You have absolutely no "non integer" maths in there anywhere.

`(screen.pt1.x + screen.pt2.x)/2` is all integers. You need to force something to be a float. Like: `(screen.pt1.x + screen.pt2.x)/2.0`

As AAT points out in the comment, you seem to be expecting to store floats into ints, so you probably need to change `point` to store floats instead of ints.

Comment: But even then you need a `double` or `float` to store the result in: so the OP needs to change `makepoint()`'s parameters as well.

Answer (score 0):

At the first place, your `Point` struct is storing `x`, `y` as int,

so for this line `middle = makepoint((screen.pt1.x + screen.pt2.x)/2,(screen.pt1.y +   screen.pt2.y)/2);`

You are having two integers coordinates anyway.

So you have to change two things:

1. Store `float` instead of `int` in struct `Point`
2. Cast / Implicit convert the number to `float` when dividing, like `(screen.pt1.x + screen.pt2.x)/2.0` as the other answer mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here.

First, `middle.x` and `middle.y` are declared as integers:

```
struct point{
       int x;
       int y;
};
```

You need to declare them as floats.

Second, `middle.x` and `middle.y` are being set to integer values.

The C operator `/` is a bit strange: When both arguments are integers, the result is an integer, so in your case, making calculations such as: `(screen.pt1.x + screen.pt2.x)/2` or `(screen.pt1.y +   screen.pt2.y)/2` will give you integers (rounded down). The solution is to make at least one of those arguments a float, by giving it precision, for example casting one of them to floats: `(float)(screen.pt1.x + screen.pt2.x)/2`, or using `2.0` (a float) instead of `2`.

---

Just an interesting fact: You can actually tell C how many decimal values you want, so in your case, you could have made your printf statement:

```
printf("x = %f.2, y = %f.2\n",middle.x,middle.y);
```

To say you want the output to be to precise to 2 decimal places. You can find a list of rules [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are holding the middle point as an integer, when it sounds like you want it to be a float.  When you do math on integers, you will end up with an integer.  Lets go through the execution of your program for a second...

We have two points, one at (0,0), and one at whatever we set.  Lets say we use (1,1)

Alright, so in the real world, we would expect our output to be 0.5, 0.5.  But, when we do integer math, we round down to the nearest. so...

(1 - 0)/2 = 0 in the integer world...

I think the part you want to change is this:

```
struct point{
       int x;
       int y;
};
```

into this:

```
struct point{
       float x;
       float y;
};
```

and the this:

```
struct point makepoint(int x, int y){
       struct point temp;

       temp.x = x;
       temp.y = y;
       return temp;
}
```

into this:

```
struct point makepoint(float x, float y){
       struct point temp;

       temp.x = x;
       temp.y = y;
       return temp;
}
```

While you're at it, you should take in floats, so you can input points in between integers.

Hope this helps!